# RecordRTC recording crash

Tags: php, html, webrtc, video-recording

According to the RecordRTC author mediarecorder api is already supported in chrome >= version 49

i download version 50 to test the features.

Any recording < 5mins result in chrome Canary crashing. how can i solve the problem?

```
audioRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                    recorderType: StereoAudioRecorder,
                    bufferSize: 16384,  // mandatory: if 720p output is forced. otherwise: optional default buffersize 16384
                    //sampleRate: 22050, // default samplerate 48000
                });

                videoRecorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
                    type: 'video', 
                    frameInterval: 90,
                    canvas:  {
                              width: 1280,
                              height: 720
                    }
                });

                videoRecorder.initRecorder(function() {
                    audioRecorder.initRecorder(function() {
                        audioRecorder.startRecording();
                        videoRecorder.startRecording();
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go to chrome://crashes and file a bug from the crash from the link provided there so the issue gets fixed before Chrome Canary becomes stable. There seem to be quite some bugs around still, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/n11m846oV4I/TWqEx0iFHQAJ)

Answer (score 1):

Use **Chrome** Canary or Beta version `>=50`. Enable this flag: `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`

Now try this RecordRTC snippet:

```
var audioVideoRecorder = RrecordRTC(yourStream, {
    type: 'video'
});
audioVideoRecorder.startRecording();
```

And now you'll NOT only get single WebM both for audio/video tracks, but also you'll be able to record minimum 10-to-15 minutes of recording **without any crash**.

If you want to **record longest-possible stream**, then you may wanna try this instead:

- https://github.com/streamproc/Record-Entire-Meeting

---

### Updated at March 03, 2016

Here is how to use MediaRecorder API to record longer streams (because RecordRTC seems currently incapable to record longer streams):

```
var recorder = new MediaRecorder(yourStream, {
    mimeType: 'video/webm'
});

recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
   if(!e || !e.data || !e.data.size) throw 'Failed.';

   yourVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(e.data);
   // UploadToServer(e.data);
};

recorder.start(3600000); // record 60 minutes video
```

You can even use `recorder.stop` to stop anytime; or `recorder.pause` to pause the recording.

Comment: i am getting error RecordRTC.js:1602 Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. when recording is more than 30mins.

Comment: @MickJack I updated the answer for MediaRecorder snippet; and it will work at least in Canary.